# In the event object for an onEdit trigger how is it that range get's defined as a real range object and a property identifier at the same time?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a little code sample to highlight the difference between an object that I created and the trigger event object.  In the trigger event object I can  use the term `e.range` along with the standard range class functions and it works fine.  However, I don't really know how to create a psuedo event object so that the range term is more than just the name of a property.

```
   function onEdit(e) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
      var sh=e.range.getSheet();//e.range is a real range object
      if(sh.getName()=='Sheet2' && e.range.columnStart>1) {
        sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e)+ '\n' + e.range.getA1Notation());
        var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.getA1Notation());//e.range is a real range object
        var myObj={value:rg.getValue,range:{columnStart:e.range.columnStart,rowStart:e.range.rowStart,columnEnd:e.range.columnEnd,rowEnd:e.range.rowEnd}};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
        try{
          sh.getRange(2,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(myObj)+ '\n' + myObj.range.getA1Notation());//myObj.range is not a real range object
        }
        catch(m) {
          console.log('Error: ' + m);
        }
        try{
          sh.getRange(3,1).setValue(e.range.getValue());
        }
        catch(n) {
          console.log('Error: ' + n);
        }
      }
    }
```

If you edit Sheet2 appropriately you will get the following Stack Driver Logs:

Stackdriver logs

```
May 29, 2020, 1:21:30 PM    Debug   {"source":{},"value":"55","user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"range":{"columnEnd":5,"columnStart":5,"rowEnd":3,"rowStart":3},"authMode":"LIMITED"}
May 29, 2020, 1:21:30 PM    Debug   {"range":{"columnStart":5,"rowStart":3,"columnEnd":5,"rowEnd":3}}
May 29, 2020, 1:21:30 PM    Debug   Error: TypeError: myObj.range.getA1Notation is not a function
```

Notice above I cannot use myObj.range with the getA1Notation() method.  (note: I didn't actually expect it to work...I'd like to know how to build the object correctly so that it will work and I haven't stumbled on the correct explanation yet.

So the thing I'd like to learn is how to create a psuedo event object so I can use `myObj.range` in the same way as I  can use `e.range`.

I feel real bad after Tanaike has gone to so much trouble.  But my real goal is to be able to create the event object precisely as it is created by the server. So that I could test onEdit()s with a test function calling the onEdit(e) rather than requiring actual edits.  And more importantly I'd really just like know how to build such an object.

I think this says what I'm shooting for.  I want to know how to create the event object precisely as it is provided to us from the onEdit trigger including having e.range to be an object that is equivalent to Class Range and thus capable of utilizing any of the methods found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).  I hope that's possible.  I apologize for these late additions but they were prompted from some of Tanaike's questions.  I'll probably need to review the question again and make it more clear.

This is some code I'm working on and it's far from complete but this is the sort of thing one might do with the knowledge of the answer to my question.

```
function onXditTest(row) {
  var row=row||2;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('OnEditTest');
  const v=sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const xsh=ss.getSheetByName(v[5]);
  const xrg=xsh.getRange(v[0],v[2],v[1]-v[0]+1,v[3]-v[2]+1);
  const evobj={range:{rowStart:v[0],rowEnd:v[1],columnStart:v[2],columnEnd:v[3]},value:v[4],range:xrg,source:ss};
  onXdit(evobj);
}
```

The real question is how to make evobj so that evobj.range is an object of Class Range and at the sametime have available evobj.range.columnStart, evobj.range.rowStart, evobj.range.columnEnd and evobj.range.rowEnd so that the code under test behaves the same way in onEdit(e) as it does in onXdit(e)

```
function onXdit(e) {//changed name so edits dont trigger the function
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.value=="TRUE" ) {
    e.source.toast('Past Condition');
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

Comment: Mostly, although it can be surprising for a question to reference an answer to itself, since it makes for a confusing chronology! I wonder if the section referring to Tanaike's work might be put in an **Update** section?

Comment: I think there is something of a consensus amongst core users (voters, curators, Meta-dwellers) that it is best to accept what worked for you, rather than to accept based on effort or sympathy. Since Tanaike is not in need of votes, I think it would be sufficient to upvote, express your gratitude in the comments under the answer, and then either (a) amend this question to be more specific about what you want, which seems to be what you have done, or (b) ask a new more specific question, linking to this old one, and specify how it is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function here is executed with the RunOnXdit button in the sidebar and it called the onXdit() function passing a psuedo onEdit trigger event object along with a mode property so that I can distinguish between running in test mode and running in live mode.

```
function onXditTest(row) {
  var row=row||2;
  console.log('row: ' + row);
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('OnEditTest');
  const v=sh.getRange(row,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const xsh=ss.getSheetByName(v[5]);
  const xrg=xsh.getRange(v[0],v[2],v[1]-v[0]+1,v[3]-v[2]+1);
  var evobj={value:v[4]?"TRUE":"FALSE",source:ss,mode:true};
  evobj.range=xrg;//assign Class Range Object
  evobj.range.rowStart=v[0];
  evobj.range.rowEnd=v[1];
  evobj.range.columnEnd=v[3];
  evobj.range.columnStart=v[2]
  onXdit(evobj);
}
```

The second function can be run from the above function or it can be run from the onEdit trigger with the same code.  The above function is generating a psuedo onEdit trigger event object.  I was totally shocked to realize how easy it was to create it.

```
function onXdit(e) {
//function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart!=5 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Section 2');
    sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue('CheckBoxIsOff')
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet2" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.range.rowStart==5  && e.value=="TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Section 2');
    sh.getRange(2,4,4,1).setValue(e.mode?"TRUE":"FALSE");
    //sh.getRange(5,4,1,1).setValue("FALSE");
    sh.getRange(2,5,4,1).setValue("");
  }
}
```

This is Sheet2 which the sheet that is to be connected to the onEdit tester

[image]

This is Sheet2 after pressing the Run OnXdit Button

[image]

It does exactly what I would have wanted the onEdit() with the same code to have done. I guess my big problem was thinking about it too much.

[image]

The image above is just a simple table for providing the appropriate event object for the onXdit() function.

Animation:

[image]

Comment: I've found this approach handy for debug complex onEdit()s. In fact I just got through with a clients job doing just that and it made it a lot easier to be able to use the debugger and single step through the code.  In a way I must apologize for asking the question because after sitting down  to code it the answer came rather quickly.  Oh well I guess is was worth it doing all the extra reading on objects any way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create an event object like the event object returned with OnEdit event trigger using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

I think that the event object from the OnEdit event trigger is returned from the internal server at Google side. So I'm not sure about the actual script for this. So in this answer, I would like to propose the method for creating the pseudo event object as you say.

In this answer, I used the JavaScript classes which can be used with V8. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect.

#### Sample script:

In order to use this script, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor, and save it. Then, please edit the cell. By this, `onEdit` is run by the OnEdit event trigger.

```
const createEventObject = obj => {
  // Class for creating the range object.
  class createRangeObject {
    constructor(obj) {
      this.columnEnd = obj.columnEnd;
      this.columnStart = obj.columnStart;
      this.rowEnd = obj.rowEnd;
      this.rowStart = obj.rowStart;
    }

    getA1Notation() {
      return SpreadsheetApp
        .getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(this.rowStart, this.columnStart, this.rowEnd - this.rowStart + 1, this.columnEnd - this.columnStart + 1)
        .getA1Notation();
    }

    getSheet() {
      return SpreadsheetApp
        .getActiveSheet();
    }
  }

  // Main script of createEventObject.
  class main {
    constructor(obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
    }

    get range() {
      return new createRangeObject(this.obj);
    }
  }
  return new main(obj);
}

// This function is run by editing cells.
function onEdit(e) {
  // This is your object.
  var myObj={range:{columnStart:e.range.columnStart,rowStart:e.range.rowStart,columnEnd:e.range.columnEnd,rowEnd:e.range.rowEnd}};

  // Create the pseudo event object.
  const obj = createEventObject(myObj.range);

  console.log(obj.range)
  console.log(obj.range.getA1Notation())
  console.log(obj.range.getSheet().getSheetName())
}
```

#### Result:

In above sample script, for example, when the cells "B3:C5" are edited, the following result are retrieved.

- `obj.range` is `{ columnEnd: 3, columnStart: 2, rowEnd: 5, rowStart: 3 }`.
- `obj.range.getA1Notation()` is `B3:C5`.
- `obj.range.getSheet().getSheetName()` is `Sheet1` which is the active sheet.

#### Note:

- This answer, which uses the JavaScript classes, is one methodology. So I think that there might be more simpler methods.
- This is a simple script for explaining of this workaround. So when you want to use this for your actual situation, please modify this.
- Please use this script with V8.

#### Reference:

- [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: That's certainly an interesting approach but what I was really looking for is being able to do this:  `function onEditTest() { //create myObject;onEdit(myObject);}` `function onEdit(e){console.log(JSON.stringify(e));//and get the correct object}`and also be able to use the e.range in exactly the same manner as we can in a normal onEdit function.

Comment: That way I could create a console on a spreadsheet or dialog and run through a bunch of tests really quickly to be able to performance test the onEdit() functions and have the code be exactly the same as if it were running due to edits.  But my  problem is that I don't know how to create event object such that e.range is actually a range.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I cannot understand about `myObject` in `onEditTest()`. And you want to run `onEditTest()`? Can I ask you about it? At first, I would like to correctly understand about your goal, and would like to modify my answer.

Comment: My real goal is to  be able to create the event object  precisely as it  is created by the server.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `myObject` in `onEditTest()` you expect. I can understand about the result values. But I cannot understand about the input values you expect. So can I ask you about the input values do you want to use? I think that in this sample script, the output values you expect is returned. So I thought that it is required to know the input value you expect.

Comment: I added some comments at the end of my question I hope that explains what I'd like to do.   But mostly I would just like to know how to create the event object that is precisely the same as the one that the server creates for the onEdit trigger.

Comment: By the way Tanaike you needn't ever apologize for anything.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. The reason that I cannot understand about your situation is due to my poor English skill. So in this case, I think that I have to apologize. About the input value, the input value you expect is an a1Notation? For example, the a1Notation of "A1" is used as the input values, and you want to return the event object as the output values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What I was trying to say is the I wan't e.range to be an object that is equivalent to Class Range and thus capable of utilizing any of the methods found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. I can understand about the output you expect. So I used the Javascript classes for this situation. By this, I thought that your goal can be achieve pseudly. But, in the current stage, Class createRangeObject has 2 methods which are `getA1Notation()` and `getSheet()`. So if you want to other methods for Class Range, it is required to add them. And also, if you want to use `e.source`, it is required to also add it. But I thought that when all methods are included, the script becomes large. So I proposed this as a simple script. How about this?

Comment: I guess I didn't really know what I was asking for.  Perhaps I should reconsider limiting those requirements. I'll have to think about that.  Maybe this really is a lousy question.  I was thinking that someone who knew a lot more about objects than I do would find this easy but maybe not.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. In order to achieve your goal, I used Javascript classes. In this case, the constructor can be return when `obj.range` is called in above script. And when the method is used like `obj.range.getA1Notation()`, `getA1Notation()` is run. I thought that this method might be able to pseudly achieve your goal. So I proposed it.

Comment: @Cooper About the additional more methods, I think that if the name of method calling for the instance of the class can be directly retrieved, the script will be simpler. But in the current stage, I'm not sure about it. This is due to my poor skill. I have to apologize for this. So in the current script I proposed, Class createRangeObject has 2 methods which are `getA1Notation()` and `getSheet()`. So if you want to use other method, you can add them. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I really want to know how the servers built the event object for the onEdit trigger.  And mostly I just want to know how to do it myself and I might be interested in using it for testing onEdit() functions but mostly I just want to know how to do it.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, I have no information about `I really want to know how the servers built the event object for the onEdit trigger.` as I said in my answer. I deeply apologize for the lack of collection of the information. When I got it, I would like to add it to my answer. And, I deeply apologize my answer is not the direction you expect. THis is due to my poor skill. I would like to study more.